# Images on Launch Screen doesn't appear on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, launch-screen

I'm building an iOS app in xcode 7. I have the standart launch screen that was autogenerated with the project, with an image view in it. I has been working fine for a while, but suddenly when I run the app, the image appears in completely black. See screen show of problem:
[image: Image showing bugged launch screen]

This only happens when I run the app on my device (iPhone 6), when I run the app on the simulator, the launche screen is as it is suppose to.

The problem occured after i edited som constraints in my storyboard, complete unrelated.
The image that is loaded is added to the project as a regular file, not in xcassets.
When i put a new, identical, image into the project the same way as the old image, it fixes the problem, but only for a couple of hours, then it happends again.

Any suggestions? I'm puzzled.!

Comment: Do you know if it's the constraints? If it is, you should be getting constraint errors or warnings when the app runs and they should be displayed into the console. Do you get any? Mine launches fine and I don't have the image in the xcassets either. I just have a UIImageView and the image on it. Also, there is a setting to launch the splashscreen by clicking into your project, and it should be about in the middle where you choose the target iOS to deploy to.

Comment: I dont get any warnings or errors, and the image (black) seems to edited properly to the constraints, i seems to have the right size and position.

Comment: So the UIImageView has your image set to your image, right? Is this a game application or a regular application?

Comment: Right. It has an image file, .png.

Comment: Try to delete the UIImageView, save, and close xCode. Reopen it, add a new UIImageView, set the image, and see what it does. have you tried running it on the Simulator as an iPhone 6?

Comment: The "App Icons and Launch Images" in the targets settings has the launchscreen.xib file, as autogenerated.
I can just change the image in the image view, and it works. And it works when I run it in the simulator without changing the imageview. 
So i can fix the problem, by changing the image, but i don't know what the source the problem is.!

Comment: Have you tried to recreate this problem by making a new project?

Comment: No, I can't even recreate the problem in the same problem, it just seems to occur at random times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experienced this problem again 1.5 years after question was asked.

**I was able to solve the problem by rebooting the iPhone :S**

I'm using the same iPhone 6 as when the question was asked, now on Xcode 8.3.1